# Amazon SP-API: put listings product : MarketplaceId is invalid

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to put a product with postman to Amazon but I always get this error message:

{
"sku": "IN-192",
"status": "INVALID",
"submissionId": "51248ab251834af6a21a976092d3ba7f",
"issues": [
{
"code": "4000006",
"message": "Unexpected marketplace identifier provided. Either the Amazon marketplace identifier is invalid, does not match the request parameters, or the seller is unauthorized to sell in the Amazon marketplace.",
"severity": "ERROR",
"categories": []
}
]
}

this is the URL :
[https://sellingpartnerapi-fe.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/{{sellerID}}/IN-192?marketplaceIds=A1VC38T7YXB528&issueLocale=en_US](https://sellingpartnerapi-fe.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/%7B%7BsellerID%7D%7D/IN-192?marketplaceIds=A1VC38T7YXB528&issueLocale=en_US)

and this body :
{
"productType": "COFFEE",
"attributes": {

```
        "contains_liquid_contents": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "はい"
            }
        ],
        "item_package_weight": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "0.65ポンド"
            }
        ],
        "manufacturer": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "Manufacturer1"
            }
        ],
        "externally_assigned_product_identifier": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "714532191586"
            }
        ],
        "recommended_browse_nodes": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "2888801"
            }
        ],
        "bullet_point": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "日本国"
            }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
            {
                "quantity": 0,
                "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_JP"
            }
        ],
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "砂糖、水あめ、植物油脂(大豆を含む)、濃縮グレープ果汁、ゼラチン"
            }
        ],
        "product_description": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": null
            }
        ],
        "supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "GHS危険物ラベル、輸送、保管"
            }
        ],
        "brand": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "Brand1"
            }
        ],
        "is_expiration_dated_product": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "はい、いいえ"
            }
        ],
        "temperature_rating": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "冷蔵：33～38度、冷凍：0度"
            }
        ],
        "country_of_origin": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "日本国、中国、英国"
            }
        ],
        "is_exclusive_product": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "はい"
            }
        ],
        "condition_type": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "新品"
            }
        ],
        "item_name": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "SUPER COFFEE"
            }
        ],
        "item_form": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "スティック"
            }
        ],
        "each_unit_count": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "4"
            }
        ],
        "list_price": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "100.0 JPY"
            }
        ],
        "number_of_items": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "5"
            }
        ],
        "merchant_suggested_asin": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "B007KQBXN0",
                "value": "日本国"
            }
        ],
        "item_package_dimensions": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "50 x 75 x 10センチメートル"
            }
        ],
        "part_number": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "RIV001"
            }
        ],
        "form_factor": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "Coffee"
            }
        ],
        "caffeine_content_description": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "カフェイン入り"
            }
        ],
        "unit_count": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "A1VC38T7YXB528",
                "value": "5"
            }
        ]
},
"requirements": "LISTING"
```

}

what might be the reason for this error message, I am using the correct marketplaceID and the seller has all the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the payload have some issue ,Check this and build on this

```
{
  "offers": [{
    "marketplaceId": "*******",
    "offerType": "B2C",
    "price": {
      "amount": "2.0",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "currencyCode": "EUR"
    }
  }],
  "requirements": "LISTING_PRODUCT_ONLY",
  "attributes": {......
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. and the documentation is only mentioning : productType , requirements and attributes

Answer (score 0):

In your payload the attribute `merchant_suggested_asin` has incorrect `marketplace_id`.
Please check that for all the attributes `marketplace_id` shall be the same, *viz.*

```
        ...
        "merchant_suggested_asin": [
            {
                "marketplace_id": "B007KQBXN0",
                "value": "日本国"
            }
        ],
        ...
```